# CefSharp IJsDialogHandler.OnBeforeUnloadDialog and UI thread

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My code for `IJsDialogHandler.OnBeforeUnloadDialog` is this:

```
bool IJsDialogHandler.OnBeforeUnloadDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string message, bool isReload, IJsDialogCallback callback)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
        "Do you want to save your work?",
        "Unsaved changes",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning
    );
    callback.Continue(dialogResult == DialogResult.No);
    return true;

    //Custom implementation would look something like
    // - Create/Show dialog on UI Thread
    // - execute callback once user has responded
    // - callback.Continue(true);
    // - return true

    //NOTE: Returning false will trigger the default behaviour, no need to execute the callback if you return false.
    //return false;
}
```

I have included the original notes that state that my dialog needs to be executed on the UI thread.

However, this code works fine.

So, is it really the UI thread that this code executes on? No need to use `Invoke` or other code?

**EDIT:**
Now, I have a simple webpage with a textarea and onbeforeunload js handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Save';
}
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

and I use:

```
bool IJsDialogHandler.OnBeforeUnloadDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string message, bool isReload, IJsDialogCallback callback)
{
    var control = (Control)browserControl;
    control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
            "Do you want to save your work?",
            "Unsaved changes",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
        );
        callback.Continue(dialogResult == DialogResult.No);
    }));
    return true;
}
```

If the user chooses to stay, I can no longer click inside the textarea to type (the cursor doesn't appear), but if I minimize my app and restore it, I can then click inside the textarea.

**EDIT2:**
Here's the working code for a custom form dialog, after `amaitland` comments:

```
var control = (Control)browserControl;
control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    using (var frm = new Form2())
    {
        var result = frm.ShowDialog();
        callback.Continue(result == DialogResult.OK);
    }
    control.Focus(); // after callback.Continue
}));
return true;
```

Comment: The method is called on the CEF UI thread which by default is not the same as the WinForms UI thread. Invoke onto the WinForms UI thread in an asynchronous fashion and executing the callback is the recommend approach. Your code may work,  it may also have unforseen consequences. From a CEF point of view it's only safe to block on the file thread as detailed in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-threads blocking on the CEF UI thread as you are doing is strongly discouraged.

Comment: So, the best approach is to cast `browserControl` to `ChromiumWebBrowser`, use `InvokeRequired` on this and if it's `true`, call `Invoke` for the dialog, if it's `false`, call the dialog itself, am I right? Or should I use `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: I'm a little lost here. If I invoke on the WinForms UI thread asynchronously, how can I use the user response in `callback.Continue` if the handler in CEF UI thread returns immediately?

Comment: You should use BeginInvoke.  See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/WinFormsRequestHandler.cs#L43 for a example that follows a similar pattern.  InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired is a simple extension method you can find in the example source.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much!

Comment: @amaitland , if you have any time, I would appreciate it if you could look my edited question, since by using `BeginInvoke` (or even `Invoke`), the cursor doesn't appear in my textarea. Should I make it a new question or post it anywhere else?

Comment: Try calling Focus on the ChromiumWebBrowser instance after the dialogue is dismissed.

Comment: @amaitland Yes, you are right! Using `control.Focus();` fixes it!!!

Comment: `control.Focus()` must be called after `callback.Continue`.